# Editing a QVariantMap from QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a QVariantMap created in C++ from a JSON object and I want to update this object from QML. I set it as a context property.

```
// main.cpp
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myjson", myqvariantmap);
```

In QML I tried updating its properties but it seems to be read-only. The [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#qvariantlist-and-qvariantmap-to-javascript-array-and-object) support this, saying

> Mind that QVariantList and QVariantMap properties of C++ types are stored as values and cannot be changed in place by QML code. You can only replace the whole map or list, but not manipulate its contents.

Is there a workaround or an alternative type I can use in place of QVariatnMap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible option is [`QQmlPropertyMap`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlpropertymap.html):

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlPropertyMap>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlPropertyMap qpropertymap;
    qpropertymap.insert("name", "foo");

    QObject::connect(&qpropertymap, &QQmlPropertyMap::valueChanged, [](const QString &key, const QVariant &value){
        qDebug() << key << value;
    });

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("qpropertymap", &qpropertymap);
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Component.onCompleted: {
        qpropertymap.name = "bar"
        // or
        // qpropertymap["name"] = "bar"
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks exactly like what I was looking for! Is there an easy way to convert to QQmlPropertyMap from QVariantMap or from QJsonObject?

Comment: @Mark The only solution I see is to iterate over QVariantMap and copy the elements to QQmlPropertyMap

Answer (score -1):

Here is a snippet to go with @eyllanesc's solution to convert from QVariantMap to QQmlPropertyMap.

```
void toPropertyMap(const QVariantMap& source, QQmlPropertyMap* dest) {
    for (const auto& key : source.keys()) {
        (*dest)[key] = source[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: You should definitely use iterators instead of `keys()` approach. Just imagine how many developers would use smth like this in their production code just because it's posted on StackOverflow by a high-ranked user.

1. `keys()` makes a new list (of strings)
2. `source[key]` is doing search on every iteration, which is itself log(n), so your code is not even linear
3. It's even worse. QQmlPropertyMap [key] is linear, so your code is n^2.

Don't blame Qt for being slow afterward.