# How to mutate list inside a QQmlPropertyMap?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a config object called `config` represented with a `QQmlPropertyMap`. It has a key called `huge_list` which is a large list of strings.

```
QVariantList hugeList = makeHugeList(); // makes a huge list of QStrings
QQmlPropertyMap config;
ownerData.insert("huge_list", hugeList);
```

How can I add, remove, or edit a particular element of `huge_list` in C++ without replacing the entire list with a new one? The issue is that `config["huge_list"]` would return a `QVariant` which does not seem to support mutation of the underlying data.

Comment: Does [QVariant::toList()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#toList) help?

Comment: You cannot signal a change to one item with QList (you might even have to manually trigger a change to this `huge_list` if you add one item). You're probably better of using QAbstractListModel or perhaps QStandardItemModel, which can do that and are well interfaced in QML

Comment: @JarMan I believe that toList makes a copy

Comment: @Amfasis I see. I got to using QQmlPropertyMap by way of trying to edit a json object from QML. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64879496/editing-a-qvariantmap-from-qml I guess editing QJsonObjects from QML cannot be done easily

Comment: You might like to use [JSONListModel](https://wiki.qt.io/JSONListModel)